# VisualStudio 2013 IntelliSense for MVC5 Razor Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC5 and whilst writing a Layout, I am wanting to include a Partial View into it.

I can do that by using the syntax like

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("{some view name that is a partial layout}"); }
```

This works when I run the application, so the question isn't about getting this to run.

My issue is when I am writing the code for `Html.` I am `not` getting the IntelliSense showing correctly for the `Html` object.

I am getting entries such as AttributeEncode, CheckBox, DropDownList, Encode, Equals etc, but I can't see `RenderPartial` in this list which is annoying.

Another thing I noticed is that the `ViewBag` and `ViewData` are not coming up in the IntelliSense when I am typing the `@`.

Everything executes fine, however I must have something configured wrong perhaps.

Does anyone know how to get the IntelliSense working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the web.config in your views folder is missing or missing some namespaces.  Make a new web app project for mvc and copy the web.config out to the views folder in your project, might fix it.

Delete the web app you made when your done.  I stick that web.config aside for safe keeping, happens to me a lot.

Comment: The issue was down to incorrect assembly version numbers in the web.configs I was using.  Unloaded and Reloaded the project, and all is working.  Thanks!